# xml linq orderby clause not working how it should be

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm having issues with the orderby clause.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elList =
    from el in doc.Descendants("Department1").Descendants("Course")
    orderby el.Attribute("Course_Code").Value ascending
    select el;
```

I tried it with a foreach and a messagebox. the messagebox displayes what it found like this : 100, 150, 170, 40, 60, 80 instead of 40, 60, 80, 10, 150, 170.
When I use the descending clause it does the same the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

you should order the *integer* values instead of *strings*

```
from el in doc.Descendants("Department1").Descendants("Course")
orderby (int)el.Attribute("Course_Code") ascending
select el;
```